# Can I Force Implicit TLS Connection For Port 587 On Postfix?

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-server, port

I have read many articles saying port 587 by default is explicit TLS. This means it's STARTTLS. It asks the server on an unsecured connection if TLS is supported and if it is, it continues with an encrypted connection. Implicit TLS (port 465) however is secure from the beginning of the connection to the end, it is never unsecure.

Just for educational purposes, say I wanted to make port 587 implicit TLS. **Would I only need to change this in the main.cf file**

smtpd_tls_security_level = may

To this:

smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt

I understand I can use port 465 for the desired result. I just wanted to make sure if implicit TLS is ALSO supported for port 587 as many articles claim so.

I understand if this is possible for 587, it would definite the purpose. The reason why port 587 is the preferred port between the two is simply because some email clients dont support encryption

Answer (score 1):

Certainly it is **possible** to put any service to listen on any port, such as SSH on port 443 (HTTPS) which is a common trick for bypassing port based firewalls. You could change this **in `master.cf`** for the `smtpd` instance listening on port `587`. However, you should not change it in `main.cf` as it will affect the instance accepting incoming mail on port `25`, too. The SMTP protocol ([RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321.html)) must begin with plain text and, thus, always uses `STARTTLS`.

Howbeit, it **does not make much sense** to create a configuration that does not follow the IANA's [Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?search=submission), the related Internet Standard [RFC 6409](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6409.html) & Proposed Standard [RFC 8314, 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8314.html#section-3.3). In practice, the *mail user agents* (MUA) i.e. the client software expect the standard ports, so they either pick the default port based on the settings or default settings based on the port. Some might not even allow such configuration altogether. You would have to configure both the server-side and the client-side to support this obscure setup. That means more confusion to your users & and requires extra documentation that could become misleading – you have already found that kind of articles. **Do not create more confusion but stick to the standards.**

Answer (score -1):

No you can't change what a port is designated for. In the case of postfix, other mailservers expect a certain "payload" when communicating over that port.

When you communicate implicit tls and another mail server handling mail for another domain where you send mail to expects explicit tls, there is a mismatch and the connection will probably be rejected by the other party.

The reason why it needs to ask over a insecure connection if tls is supported, in the case a mailserver where you send mail to, doesn't support tls, i cant answer when everything is tls,and your mailserver doesn't have a answer.

And let's imagine that mailserver is from your biggest clients, you do want to send mail to, so it answers i can't do tls, and your mailserver falls back to non tls, and the mailservers are still able to handle your mail. In the case it isn't able to handle the mail for you or your company you might lose millions of dollars.

When doing tls, in the most cases there is a fallback from secure to non secure

I tried to make it practical for you with an example for better understanding.

Comment: Thank you Ace. That was helpful. So would you recommend port 587 for email clients?

Comment: Enail clients? I just explained you the mail server to server communication. The option you stated is also not for a client communication smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt

Comment: The submission 587 and submissions 465 are not used by other mail servers. MTA to MTA always uses port 25.

Comment: A lot of mailservers nowadays uses ports 587 for submission, also because some ISP are blocking port 25.

Comment: For *submission* but never for SMTP. Those are two different protocols for different use cases.